# MultiByteToWideChar doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I'm trying to use `MultiByteToWideChar` api. for `lpWideCharStr`, when I use a pointer with dynamic memory allocation, it works properly. but now I should use a pointer with static memory allocation as you see in the code. and it doesn't work properly, return 0.

what's wrong with it?

how should I use a static memory allocated pointer for `lpWideCharStr` in `MultiByteToWideChar`?

thank's for your solutions.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Shlwapi.h"

#pragma comment(lib,"shlwapi.lib")

void main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int iToSizeB = 0;
    iToSizeB = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, argv[1], -1 , NULL, 0);

    LPWSTR lpFileAddress[260] = {0};
    int nResult = 0;

    //MultiByteToWideChar function reurns 0 !!!
    nResult = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, argv[1], -1, lpFileAddress[0], iToSizeB);
}
```

Comment: You should get a diagnostic message for this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you mean this:

```
WCHAR lpFileAddress[260] = {0};
nResult = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, argv[1], -1, lpFileAddress, iToSizeB);
```

In your code, you define array of WCHAR pointers: `LPWSTR lpFileAddress[260]` instead of `WCHAR` array, as required: `WCHAR lpFileAddress[260] = {0};`

Comment: what's the `WSTR` datatype? it's unknown in my IDE. I'm using VS 2012.

Comment: `iToSizeB` can be greater than 260. KABOOM!